# Can I get data from a table based on multiple other tables?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, mysqli

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table3 WHERE name_id = '(SELECT name_id FROM table2
WHERE salary < 1000 && name = '(SELECT name FROM table1
WHERE savings > 1000)')'";
```

Basically I want to get the data from the table1 based on the savings and use it to get the data from table 2 and use that data to get all the information from table 3. But this wont work. Is my code right or am I doing something wrong?

I also cannot create new tables, I simply want to display the data from table 3.

Comment: why are you not using joins?

Answer (score 2):

Use `join`

```
SELECT * FROM table3 t3 join table2 t2 
on t3.name_id=t2.name_id
join table1 t1
on t3.name=t1.name
where salary < 1000 and savings > 1000
```

Comment: what are t3, t2, and t1?

Comment: t3, t2, and t1 are aliases name of table3,table2,table1 **aliases are used to temporarily rename a table** @Matt.Doe

Answer (score 1):

```
$query="SELECT * FROM table3 LEFT JOIN table2 ON    table3.name_id=table2.name_id
LEFT JOIN table1 ON table3.name=table1.name 
WHERE table2.salary < 1000  AND table1.savings > 1000 "
```

Answer (score 0):

Another syntax of join is

```
SELECT * FROM table1 t1,table2 t2 ,table3 t3 
where t1.name = t3.name and 
t2.name_id = t3.name_id and 
t1.savings > 1000 and t2.salary < 1000;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT t3.* FROM table3 t3 
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.name_id = t3.name_id AND t2.salary < 1000
INNER JOIN table1 t1 ON t1.name = t2.name AND t1.savings > 1000";
```

Comment: Add some explanation to your query